QGIS - Get the nearests neighbors from a WMS layer
Usually, to retreive the nearests neighbors between two vector layers, I will use the algorithm "Join attributes by nearest".
In my situation, I have a vector layer and many WMS layers.
Is there a way to get the nearest features from the WMS layers (with a distance that I can specify).
Here is an example:
!](https://i.sstatic.net/65LZ6jzB.png)
I have a rectangular polygon in the middle, and I would like to list, into the attribute table of the rectangle polygon, all the features that are located under 10km.
Is there a way to do that ?
I tried converting the WMS layer into a vector layer but it doesn't work.
Also looked into some other algorithm like Distance matrix.
usage: gdal_polygonize.py [--help] [--help-general] [-q] [-8] [-o name=value] 
[-mask filename] [-nomask] [-b band] 
[-of ogr_format] [-lco name=value] [-overwrite] 
src_filename dst_filename [dst_layername] 
[dst_fieldname] 
gdal_polygonize.py: error: the following arguments are required: dst_filename
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 138, in on_stderr
val = ba.data().decode('UTF-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 81: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray'> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray'> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 133, in processAlgorithm
GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback)
File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 154, in runGdal
res = proc.run(feedback)
SystemError: <built-in method run of QgsBlockingProcess object at 0x000001E6E818DC10> returned a result with an error set


A WMS layer is a picture of the data, you need to look for a WFS endpoint to the data

As explained by Ian Turton, a WMS layer is a picture. I cannot get information the way I want from it. I will look for a WFS service.
